# Running viewshed analysis in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, viewshed

Can I run a viewshed analysis in ArcGIS Online, or would I need an ArcGIS Desktop / Spatial Analyst licence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the create viewshed analysis tool in ArcGIS Online.

If you have an ArcGIS Online organizational account and the privileges to create, update, and delete the contents, you can access the analysis tools.

1. In the ArcGIS Online Map Viewer navigate to Analysis--> Find Locations--> Create Viewshed
2. Refer to this link([Create Viewshed](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/create-viewshed.htm)) for a better understanding

. [image: List item]